# Mocking a list which returns clone object in setter

Tags: junit, mockito

I'm trying to mock a list

```
counted[binModel.getX() - 1][binModel.getY() - 1].add(activeModel);
```

`add` is a `boolean` and I'm trying this

```
Mockito.when(testee.getCounted()[binModel.getSelectionX() - 1]
    [binModel.getSelectionY() - 1].add(activeModel)).thenReturn(Mockito.anyBoolean());
```

This throws an error on

```
public List<CountModel>[][] getCounted() {
    return counted.clone();
}
```

`counted` is declared in the original class as

```
private List<CountModel>[][] counted;
```

This is the error:

> null pointer and for @mock private List[][] counted; Mockito cannot mock/spy following: - final classes - anonymous classes - primitive types

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: null pointer and for 
@mock private List<CountModel>[][] counted;
 Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
  - final classes
  - anonymous classes
  - primitive types

Comment: Can you post larger scope of your code. It seems to me that you are not stubbing a mock but a real class.

Answer (score 3):

An array is a final class in java, so it cannot be mocked.

What you might have to do is fill up the array with mocks yourself, for example...

```
// Lose the @Mock annotation if that's how you set it up
private List<CountModel>[][] counted;

@Before
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void setup() {
    counted = new List[X_SIZE][Y_SIZE];

    for(int x = 0; x < X_SIZE; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < Y_SIZE; y++) {
            counted[x][y] = mock(List.class);
        }
    }
}
```

(Not sure why you really want to mock a list though)

To get round the "clone" thing, you could either construct another mock to represent the cloned list or just return the same list...

```
@Before
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public void setup() {
    counted = new List[X_SIZE][Y_SIZE];

    for(int x = 0; x < X_SIZE; x++) {
        for(int y = 0; y < Y_SIZE; y++) {
            counted[x][y] = mock(List.class);
            when(counted[x][y].clone()).thenReturn(counted[x][y]);
        }
    }
}
```

Like I said, it's probably not the best use of mocks to mock the list. Maybe create a real list that has mock "CountModels" in or something?

(You might have to post your full code in order to give me a bit more of an idea of what you are trying to do)

Comment: +1, especially for not mocking a list. There's nothing to be gained there; it's purely an overuse of mocks.

Comment: All I want is the test to pass through that step. May be there is another to let the test pass through it other than mocking it